# UpdateModel without validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, modelbinders

Is there a possibility in ASP.NET MVC3 to set the properties of a view model from a `FormCollection` without invoking validation specified by validation attributes on the properties?
`UpdateModel<T>(T model)` also invokes validation.

**The background:**

I can only validate the model if a connection to the database is present, but this connection can only be established, if the data from one specific form field is correct (kind of an access code for each organisation). If the connection is not established, an exception is thrown.

When the data entered in this field is incorrect, I don't want to loose the values entered in all other form fields, but present the already entered values again to the user and give him a change to correct the errors.

So what I need is basically something like conditional validation or no validation by the model binder at all.
Is there anything like this built-in in ASP.NET MVC or do I need to write my own UpdateModel method, calling a (custom) model binder?

Answer (score 2):

Why not pass the viewmodel into your method, rather than formscollection? That way you can do

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Update(UpdateViewModel model)
{
    if (!Model.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

So if the validation fails your user is going to be directed back to the Update view, with the model already populated from the information they submitted.

Now, in my opinion, having a validation attribute require a database connection, which in turn can throw exceptions is the wrong way to go about this. Those sorts of validation I move to a validation service, which is injected into the controller (and takes in the repository stuff it needs via DI as well). Each validation service will take in a view model and return a collection of ValidationResult instances, which I then attach to the model [validation result](http://silk.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/f6d66fe0578a#MileageStats/MileageStats.Domain/Contracts/ValidationResult.cs)s via an [extension method](http://silk.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/f6d66fe0578a#MileageStats/MileageStats.Web/ControllerExtensions.cs) to the Controller class (both lifted from the Project Silk stuff MS P&P is pushing out)

This allows for easier testing as you can mock up the repository and have it return the correct results for testing ...

Comment: The validation logic (implemented as validation attributes) throws an exception, if no connection to the database is available (which isn't the case at this point of time). So steps are: 1. check whether the value of fieldA is correct - 2. Connect to a database based on the value of fieldA - 3. Update and validate model. Steps 2 and 3 aren't possible if value of fieldA is invalid. Of course, I could just catch the exceptions, but these are exceptions thrown by EF, which itself is "hidden" behind a repository pattern. So it wouldn't be a clean solution.

Comment: Ah ok, then, you're doing it wrong *grin* Will expand my answer

Comment: Thanks for your extensive explanation. Your right that the overall design might not be optimal, but my actual question was more generally targeted whether there actually is a way to update a model without validation. Thus I am still gone leave it open. Maybe someone comes up with an idea.